# How to convert a date stored in a macro variable into sas format

Tags: sas

I have a macro valiable `%let date = '31DEC2015'd;` (1451550706498 in table in  sas format)

How can I convert it into SAS format to apply filter on my table, how can I do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

There is no conversion needed. If you have a date column in your sas dataset, you can simply filter it by using your macro variable this way:

```
data filtered;
  set unfiltered;
  where dateCol <= &date;
run;
```

Although the number you mention cannot plausibly refer to the date you mention -- 31DEC2015 has a numerical value of `20,453` in SAS (*elapsed days since January 1st 1960*). So there is something odd with your data... Even with a datetime (# of seconds elapsed since Jan 1st 1960), the figure is around `1,767,139,200 secs.`, nowhere near your numeric value. How did you get that huge number?

---

### EDIT

Not 100% sure I fully understand what you're asking, but here's an alternative to the solution you mentioned in the comments, which will give you a "real" SAS date, that is, still numeric, but one to which you can apply any SAS date format:

```
data test;
  format newDate date9.;
  oldDateTime = 1451550706498;
  oldDate = datepart(oldDateTime/1000);
  newDate = intnx("YEAR",oldDate,-10,"SAME");
  put _ALL_;
run;
```

Results:

```
newDate=30DEC1995 oldDateTime=1.4515507E12 oldDate=16800
```

(I see there is a 1-day difference from your results though.)

If you need to filter based on this value (through a macro variable), you can always use CALL SYMPUT to assign it.

Comment: here is my conversion from sas data type to date:--put(dhms('01jan1970'd,3,0,date/1000),datetime9.)

Comment: Oh I see, it's that huge number you're starting from... See my edit for another solution.